# How to arrange database for finding a word by searching with synonyms that I define?

Tags: database, search, database-design, synonym

I'm attempting to create a simple tool that will allow users to search through about 200 words by using synonyms defined by me.

**Example:** The word in the set is *"fire"*. The user can search *fire*, *flame*, *flames*, *matches*, etc (I put these in)...and it will return *"fire"*.

**Initial Thoughts:** My immediate thought was to just have a two column table, where the first column is the *actual* word, and the second column is an appropriate synonym:

```
ACTUAL             SYNONYM
fire               flame
fire               flames
fire               matches
```

So when the user searches, I would do a simple select:

```
SELECT actual WHERE synonym = "THE SEARCH TERM"
```

**Question:** How should I set up my database for searching these words and associate them with synonyms? Is my proposed solution the best/most efficient way? I feel like I ought to be able to have one row per "actual", and just put ALL synonyms in the second column, but I don't know how I would search this second column, or if it would even be more efficient than just a straight list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your synonyms each map back to exactly one "actual" or core word, what you have is fine.  Then it's just

```
select ACTUAL from Your_Table where SYNONYM = "The_Search_Term"
```

and you'll get back zero or one records.

I might use a `like` clause instead if your synonyms are dissimilar enough, so you don't need to mess with plurals:

```
select ACTUAL from Your_Table where SYNONYM like "%The_Search_Term%"
```

That way you don't need to include both `flame` and `flames`; `flame` will work for both.

Comment: Sounds good. I don't imagine each "actual" having more than 20 synonyms, so the table isn't ever going to become terribly huge. I feel stupid for having left out the FROM and having not used LIKE. It's been too long since I've done SQL, haha. Thank you for your help!

Comment: My pleasure. You didn't specify SQL so I wouldn't have called that an oversight. I got what you were saying. The `LIKE` may reduce the size of the table but you'll be increasing the chance of multiple results.  If one of your synonyms is `cat` and another one is `scatter` then you'll return more than one row with the `LIKE` query.

Comment: Hmm, good point. Multiple results isn't a huge deal, but I'll mess around with it. Enjoy your evening!